# How to replace numbers with centered strings in dcolumn table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn, xtable

In a table produced by the `texreg::texreg()` function in `R` I want to replace numerical values with strings. The purpose is to summarize values of a bunch of control variables with a single line and a simple `"yes"`.

My problem is that the `yes`es aren't centered. So my idea was to add some white-space before but it won't work with any method I know. Probably it'll be removed somehow.

This is the original line to be modified.

```
groupTrt    & -0.37      \\
            & (0.31)     \\
```

And this is my code:

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{2.5} }
\hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} \\
\hline
(Intercept) & 5.03^{***} \\
            & (0.22)     \\
Controls    &   \quad yes   \\
Controls    &   ~yes   \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.07       \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.02       \\
Num. obs.   & 20         \\
RMSE        & 0.70       \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

But neither `\quad` nor `~` seems to have an effect:

[image]

I also tried `\  yes` but without success.

My expected output would be something like this (photoshopped):

[image]

How do I center my `yes`es?

**Note:** Originally I wanted to [write an own function using the `xtable` package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58053275/6574038) that **1.** automatically removes selected rows from a former function output, and **2.** inserts custom rows with numbers, placeholders or text. Now I'm facing a similar issue with texreg.

Comment: You can use for example `\multicolumn{1}{c}{yes}`. I'd also suggest to replace the `center` environment with the `\centering` command as the former will add some additional vertical white space when used in combination with `table`.

Comment: @leandriis Great, `\multicolumn` works!! Replacing `center` environment seems to have no effect, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by *@leandriis* in the comments we can use a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{yes}` within the table.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{2.5} }
\hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} \\
\hline
(Intercept) & 5.03^{***} \\
            & (0.22)     \\
Controls    &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{yes}   \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.07       \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.02       \\
Num. obs.   & 20         \\
RMSE        & 0.70       \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

**Result**
[image]